# Weird symbol "@" appearing in openstack libvirt logs prior to reboot"

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Can someone offer some suggestions:

```
D, [2018-11-08T10:15:07.131405 #5191] DEBUG -- : rabbitmq.rb:66:in `on_hbfire' Publishing heartbeat to stomp://mcollective@10.180.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: send_fire, {:curt=>1541672107.1311357, :last_sleep=>30.499510526657104}
D, [2018-11-08T10:15:10.870564 #5191] DEBUG -- : rabbitmq.rb:64:in `on_hbfire' Received heartbeat from stomp://mcollective@10.180.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: receive_fire, {:curt=>1541672110.8702872}
D, [2018-11-08T10:15:37.631521 #5191] DEBUG -- : rabbitmq.rb:66:in `on_hbfire' Publishing heartbeat to stomp://mcollective@10.180.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: send_fire, {:curt=>1541672137.6312556, :last_sleep=>30.49948763847351}
D, [2018-11-08T10:15:40.371089 #5191] DEBUG -- : rabbitmq.rb:64:in `on_hbfire' Received heartbeat from stomp://mcollective@10.180.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: receive_fire, {:curt=>1541672140.3708408}
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.214327 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:167:in `loadclass' Loading Mcollective::Facts::Yaml_facts from mcollective/facts/yaml_facts.rb
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.244378 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:44:in `<<' Registering plugin facts_plugin with class MCollective::Facts::Yaml_facts single_instance: true
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.244493 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:167:in `loadclass' Loading Mcollective::Connector::Rabbitmq from mcollective/connector/rabbitmq.rb
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.251263 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:44:in `<<' Registering plugin connector_plugin with class MCollective::Connector::Rabbitmq single_instance: true
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.251381 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:167:in `loadclass' Loading Mcollective::Security::Psk from mcollective/security/psk.rb
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.257725 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:44:in `<<' Registering plugin security_plugin with class MCollective::Security::Psk single_instance: true
D, [2018-11-08T10:32:42.257951 #5439] DEBUG -- : pluginmanager.rb:167:in `loadclass'
```

Comment: These logs looks to be coming from puppet?

Comment: Yeah, I found out that the issue is a bad connection and it is a broken SSH tunnel command.

Comment: Thanks though :D